# When is setbuf useful (besides the NULL value)?

Tags: c++, c

When is the `setbuf` function useful (except the NULL value)?

I try to invent the examples, but I can't still.
I understand how `setvbuf` can be useful, but I don't understand with `setbuf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `setvbuf` is a newer API to the same logic as `setbuf`. `setbuf` exists for compatibility  with programs that were written before `setvbuf` existed.

So in other words, unless you're dealing with code that already uses `setbuf`, just ignore that it exists.

[Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html):

> **Function:** `void setbuf (FILE *stream, char *buf)`
>
> - If `buf` is a null pointer, the effect of this function is equivalent to calling `setvbuf` with a mode argument of `_IONBF`. Otherwise, it is equivalent to calling `setvbuf` with `buf`, and a mode of `_IOFBF` and a size argument of `BUFSIZ`.
> - The setbuf function is provided for compatibility with old code; use setvbuf in all new programs.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible cases:

1. In the (unlikely)_ case you want to "optimize" your I/O buffer, you can use [setvbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf).
2. You might wish to buffer into memory you control directly (either setbuf or setvbuf)

... and ...

3. You might wish to turn buffering OFF (or turn it back ON: again, either setbuf or setvbuf).

REFERENCE:

[Beej's Guide to C](https://kountanis.com/beej-c-programming-mirror/), [40.9 setbuf(), setvbuf()](https://kountanis.com/beej-c-programming-mirror/#man-setbuf)

Comment: 1) -> No, as I know... The buffer's size always must to be the BUFSIZ.

Comment: `setvbuf` allows you to redefine the buffer size for that IO stream. `setbuf` is setvbuf with the buffer size auto-set to BUFSIZ.

Comment: The link is dead. After a `setvbuf(f, NULL, _IONBUF, 0)` how would I re-enable previous buffering?

Comment: https://www.beej.us/guide/bgc/source/man/setbuf.c  See also: [Mirror of Beej's Guide to C Programming](https://kountanis.com/beej-c-programming-mirror/)